# Python OpenCV find triangles from the given icosahedron image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

Given this [image](https://www.pngtube.com/myfile/full/382-3825690_everything-is-possible-geometric-shapes-icosahedron.png) an icosahedron, I need to find the number of triangles in it.

following is the code for the same

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import imutils

# loading image and thresholding
img = cv2.imread('382-3825690_everything-is-possible-geometric-shapes-icosahedron.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
# plt.imshow(thresh)
# plt.show()
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(contours)

# getting triangles
img_1 = img.copy()
triangles_found = 0
for c in cnts:
  peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
  approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
  if len(approx) == 3:
    triangles_found += 1
    # cv2.drawContours(img_1, c, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3) 
    # plt.imshow(img_1)
    # plt.show()
```

[image]

The `triangles_found = 14` after execution, but when I drew contours the contours where not triangles

please can some one guide me how to extract the triangles ?

Comment: The server where image was stored is not found. Please reattach to question by using the upload tool provided with the question.

Comment: @ZF007 I have uploaded the image. Thank you

Comment: Interesting image. I assume the first ten (solid lines) will go correctly? There is one dotted line missing at the bottom that should split the diamond shape in two pieces or is this intentionally left out?

Comment: Yes, solid lines forming the ten triangles are the target

Comment: After `threshold` I would suggest to increase the canvas size by at least two pixels each direction to remove the four corner detected triangles. Then I would find the corners of each triangle and annotate n pixes from corner centers rather than finding leg/inner-surface interface locations of each triangle. This would remove the dotted lines attached to legs. Finally, if you update to openCV 4.x the copy functions are depreciated and won't work.